# User Defaults not saved

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsuserdefaults

I've got a NSTableView, with 1 column, whos "Content" is binded to user defaults and the column "Value" is also binded.

**My code is here - https://gist.github.com/6df8d2e338c0595c1ef9**

For some reason, if I run my application, add/remove items, then quit and re-launch, nothing's been saved and the table is as it was when I first originally started it. **Why isn't it saving?**

If you take a look at the link above (my code), I am calling [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your array in NSUserDefaults is immutable. This is why it won't work.

Use a NSArrayController and bind your column to it's arrangedObjects.
Then bind the content of the NSArrayController to your user defaults.

Comment: Shall I drag an NSArrayController in, in Interface Builder, set the class of it to my app delegate, as that has the array etc. then how do I bind the NSArrayController to my user defaults?